# How to make gcc print errors/messages in short format (without citations from source)

Tags: gcc, error-messaging

When I compile my source, gcc generates messages in following format:

```
apue.h:97:17: note: ‘#pragma message: _POSIX_ADVISORY_INFO = 200809L’
   97 |         #pragma message "_POSIX_ADVISORY_INFO = " XSTR(_POSIX_ADVISORY_INFO)
      |                 ^~~~~~~
apue.h:100:17: note: ‘#pragma message: _POSIX_CPUTIME = 0’
  100 |         #pragma message "_POSIX_CPUTIME = " XSTR(_POSIX_CPUTIME)
      |                 ^~~~~~~
...
```

But I want gcc to generate messages in following format:

```
apue.h:97:17: note: ‘#pragma message: _POSIX_ADVISORY_INFO = 200809L’
apue.h:100:17: note: ‘#pragma message: _POSIX_CPUTIME = 0’
...
```

Which option can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the source citations omitted only for `#pragma message` then you
cannot do this with a commandline option. You would need to pipe the build log through
an external filter.

If you are content for source citations to be omitted for *all* diagnostics, then use the option `-fno-diagnostics-show-caret`. See the [GCC Manual: 3.7 Options to Control Diagnostic Messages Formatting](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Message-Formatting-Options.html)